# Почему падает телеграм бот?

Tags: python, ubuntu, telegram-bot, requests

*Всем привет! Запускаю телеграм бота он работает несколько часов, потом падает по ошибки ниже. Подскажите , пожалуйста, как исправить.(запускаю на сервере Ubuntu 18.04)*

**Зависимости:**

```
pyTelegramBotAPI==3.7.1
requests==2.23.0
firebase==3.0.1
firebase-admin==4.3.0
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.25.9
```

**kokoto.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=uba
After=network.target

[Service]
User=kokoto
Group=kokoto

WorkingDirectory=/home/kokoto/uba/
Environment="PYTHONPATH=/home/kokoto/uba/"
ExecStart=/home/kokoto/uba/.venv/bin/python /home/kokoto/uba/bot_bd.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Ошибка**

```
kokoto.service - uba
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kokoto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-09-23 17:38:16 MSK; 1h 22min ago
Process: 21132 ExecStart=/home/kokoto/uba/.venv/bin/python /home/kokoto/uba/bot_bd.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 21132 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 23 17:38:16 s307229 python[21132]:     timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
Sep 23 17:38:16 s307229 python[21132]:   File "/home/kokoto/uba/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
Sep 23 17:38:16 s307229 python[21132]:     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
Sep 23 17:38:16 s307229 python[21132]:   File "/home/kokoto/uba/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
Sep 23 17:38:16 s307229 python[21132]:     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
Sep 23 17:38:16 s307229 python[21132]:   File "/home/kokoto/uba/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
Sep 23 17:38:16 s307229 python[21132]:     raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
Sep 23 17:38:16 s307229 python[21132]: requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)
Sep 23 17:38:16 s307229 systemd[1]: kokoto.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 23 17:38:16 s307229 systemd[1]: kokoto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Связь с Telegram прерывается... Либо в вашем регионе Telegram блокируется, либо у Вас проблемы с интернетом.

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/474

Comment: @Sadykhzadeh мне хостинг провайдер утверждает что у них с инетом все гуд

Answer (score 0):

Уверен, что проблема в блокировках Telegram на территории РФ.

Возможные решения:

```
Использовать VPN
Использовать Прокси (нужен socks с SSL, возможно, придется отключить проверку сертификата)
Хостить бота на зарубежном облаке
```

---

Если бот крутится на локальной машине -> прокси либо ВПН (я использовал tor).
Если бот крутится на хостинге -> арендуй забугорный хостинг.

---

Comment: Блокировку же сняли